# How to call a simple method declared in same ViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uiviewcontroller

I have declared a method in a view controller as:

```
-(void)rqst_run{
     // method login here
}
```

When I wrote the code below (in the same file) in ViewDidLoad method after [super viewDidLoad];

```
[self rqst_run];
```

I get this error:

```
Method '-rqst_run' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Thx in advance

Stephane

Comment: This is a compiler error, right? Have you declared the rqst_run method in the .h file?

Comment: I realise I misread this - when you say error, do you in fact mean a warning (potentially made into an error by -Werror)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Methods need to be declared before they're used.

You can solve your issue in one of two ways:

- Move the declaration of rqst_run to before the declaration of viewDidLoad
- Declare rqst_run in the @interface section for your class (either in the .h, or a class continuation in your .m)

The second is the best of those, so you would, for example, add something akin to the below at the top of your .m

```
@interface MyClass()
- (void) rqst_run;
@end
```

If you're not familiar with the concept of class continuations, [this page](http://theocacao.com/document.page/516/) offers a reasonable summary; in essence, an @interface section in the .m for declarations that you want kept out of the "public interface" (i.e. the .h)

Comment: yes I got it it! I've got some bad habits with PHP...Thank You!!